# Failed to start MySQL Community Server

Tags: server, mysql

I'm trying install mysql but I can not start the server.

The `journalctl -xe` return this:

```
Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
oct 24 18:37:11 carlosPc audit[20528]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/
oct 24 18:37:11 carlosPc audit[20528]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/
oct 24 18:37:11 carlosPc audit[20528]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/
oct 24 18:37:11 carlosPc kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1508863031.769:402): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" 
oct 24 18:37:11 carlosPc kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1508863031.769:403): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" 
oct 24 18:37:11 carlosPc kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1508863031.769:404): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" 
oct 24 18:37:14 carlosPc systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
oct 24 18:37:41 carlosPc systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
oct 24 18:37:41 carlosPc systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state. 
oct 24 18:37:41 carlosPc systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
oct 24 18:37:42 carlosPc systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
oct 24 18:37:42 carlosPc systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
oct 24 18:37:42 carlosPc systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
oct 24 18:37:42 carlosPc audit[20630]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/
oct 24 18:37:42 carlosPc audit[20630]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/
oct 24 18:37:42 carlosPc audit[20630]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/
oct 24 18:37:42 carlosPc kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1508863062.269:405): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" 
oct 24 18:37:42 carlosPc kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1508863062.269:406): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" 
oct 24 18:37:42 carlosPc kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1508863062.269:407): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open"
```

Comment: AppArmor is blocking the execution.  How'd you install MySQL?

Comment: Did `sudo command` play a role in its install?

Comment: @ThomasWard I don't remember how I installed MySQL. I think I installed following this tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04). Doing `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`